# Dúvida com relação ao algoritmo minimax

Tags: algoritmo, algoritmo-de-busca

O minimax, por definição, é ótimo caso os dois jogadores atuem de forma ótima, certo? No entanto, podemos afirmar algo quando um deles joga de forma ótima e o outro não? No caso do jogo da velha, como o espaço de estados é pequeno, o jogador que atua com minimax nunca perde para um jogador aleatório por conseguir explorar toda a árvore de busca. E no caso de um jogo com maior espaço, como Damas? O que podemos afirmar quando um jogador faz jogadas ruins contra outro que atua com minimax? O minimax não será mais ótimo, é isso mesmo?

By definition, the minimax algorithm is optimal only if the two players that are playing against each other perform optimally, isn't it? However, can we say something when one of them plays optimal and the other does not? More precisely, what can we say when a player makes bad plays (bad moves) against another player with minimax with the aim that the minimax player plays worse (make some bad moves)? Thanks!!

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Traduza sua questão

Comment: Olá, Jefferson. Coloquei em português também ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Algoritmo Minimax é ótimo no sentido de que sempre fará a jogada que minimiza a perda máxima (por isso se chama MiniMax), esse fato independe de como o outro jogador joga, é claro que dependendo da jogado do adverśario, a resposta que minimiza a perda máxima pode ser diferente, mas o algoritmo sempre escolhe a jogada ótima para ele naquela situação, é importante notar que ótimo significa **o melhor possível** e não a jogada perfeita, é possível jogar de forma ótima e perder (ou empatar) o jogo, simplesmente porquê a menor perda máxima possível é maior que 0.
Assim, a resposta pra sua pergunta é: independente do adversário, o Minimax sempre fará a jogada ótima, com a métrica sendo a menor perda máxima possível, para jogos com o espaço de busca maior, a árvore se torna muito grande, nesses casos usam-se outros algoritmos (como o [alpha-beta prunning](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poda_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))) que é uma variação do Minimax.